# Routing in Web forms not working

Tags: asp.net, routes, global-asax

This is the code in Global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Page1","{Param1}/{Param2}","~/FirstPage.aspx");

System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Page2","Xyz/{Param3}","~/Second.aspx");   
}
```

Now i'm trying to redirect to some page e.g. xyz/test1,xyz/test2,xyz/test3. It's always getting redirected to FirstPage, not the second page which is what is expected and i'm trying to do.

How to implement this? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure below important things are met before you start creating routing,

•Define custom URL patterns that are not dependent on physical file names.
•Generate URLs based on route URL parameter values by using markup or code. 
•In a routed page, retrieve values passed in URL segments by using markup or code.

Try below code to implement routing,
1. In Application_start method you can only register the routes as below,

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 }
```

2. Create below method after Session_End method in you global.asax file,
   void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
   }
3. In the RegisterRoutes method, add the following code,

   routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
   "SalesReport/{locale}/{year}",
   "~/sales.aspx");

This code adds a route that is named SalesRoute. You are naming this route because it has the same parameter list as the route that you will create in the following step. Assigning names to these two routes enables you to differentiate them when you generate URLs for them.

More details refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx